# Angular Material Automcomplete filtering

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a json object like the following:

```
[
   {
      "personId":"ac9be7ef-ab23-4ed9-a77e-7e844f5ef902",
      "fullName":"X1, X1."
   },
   {
      "personId":"5a88203a-e69e-4103-bc05-b99c83f1a6cd",
      "fullName":"X2, X2"
   },
   {
      "personId":"17a39787-2122-4149-b767-d8075cd42c1a",
      "fullName":"X3, X3"
   }
]
```

and I want to use autocomplete component to filter out people.

I have defined my formControl like that:

```
fromControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
```

and in the html I have it like that

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
   <mat-label>From</mat-label>
   <input type="text"
   placeholder="Type in the person name"
   aria-label="Text"
   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
   matInput
   [formControl] = "fromControl"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto">
   <mat-icon matSuffix>person</mat-icon>
   <mat-error *ngIf="fromControl?.hasError('required')">
      From client selection is required!
   </mat-error>
   <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of from" [value]="c.personId">
      {{ c.fullName }}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Right now when clicking inside the control or filtering options it will populate all the names/filtered names, however, when choosing a name it will put the personId in the control as the selected value.

The displayed value should still be the fullName

Here is my stackBlitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aoqyte?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html)

Comment: Do you wanna display the name in the input? try this {{ option.fullName }} will display the name in the input.

Comment: The stackblitz example is filtering properly, but on the selection of the name, it is showing the personId rather than the selected name.. this weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
   <mat-label>From</mat-label>
   <input type="text"
   placeholder="Type in the person name"
   aria-label="Text"
   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
   matInput
   [formControl] = "fromControl"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto">
   <mat-icon matSuffix>person</mat-icon>
   <mat-error *ngIf="fromControl?.hasError('required')">
      From client selection is required!
   </mat-error>
   <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of from" [value]="option.fullName">
      {{ option.fullName }} 
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi, Hamada. If you see my stackblitz example, I am using option.fullName.. but when you select the option then it will put the personId rather than the selected name in the autocomplete box

Comment: in both in Value and Input option.fullName? and get the id in the Method.

Comment: I thought about this, but the whole autocomplete behavior is just weird to me. If this is how it is done through a selectionChange event then it is what it is. Thank you Hamada